# Passing Java functions as arguments and typechecking response

Tags: java, wamp, deferred, typechecking

I need to pass an arbitrary Java method to another class where it will be executed asynchronously. I have a feeling I can use lambda functions as the parameters of my call method, but I'm not sure if I need to create a functional interface for it. I will also need to typecheck the response.

```
private Object foo(String method, Object...args){
    try{
        result.set( connection.invoke(method, args) );
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }

    return result.get();
}
```

[I noticed someone wanted to do something similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977994/passing-named-functions-as-arguments), but I need to pass an arbitrary number of arguments (BiConsumer only works for 2). I don't know how many arguments I will need call to accept.

I also need to typecheck the response, and everything I've found so far regarding Java typechecking says this is not possible. Is it?

Comment: Typechecking the response can be done using `getClass()` on the returned object

Comment: What if my arguments have primitives?

Comment: The connection with RMI escapes me. RMI is not asynchronous, for a start.

Comment: You cannot mix plain primitives with objects, you have to choose. At most what you can do is use wrapper for primitives with boxing/unboxing mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make varargs methods with the following signature:

```
interface Invokable extends FunctionalInterface {
    Object invoke(Object... arguments);
}
```

Primitive can be passed as argument since they will be auto boxed to their object equivalent (int -> Integer, long -> Long, and so on).

However, you will be forced to use cast to do type checking.

What I recommend instead is to use an `Object`containing the arguments and to parametrize the functional interface:

```
interface Argument<R> {
    // Empty interface used to mark argument types.
}

interface Invokable<R, A extends Argument<R>> extends FunctionalInterface {
    R invoke(A argument);
}
```

And then change your `foo` method to find the method to call depending on the argument class. Like so:

```
private <A, R> R foo(A arg) {
    if (arg != null) {
        // TODO: Use injection or a map to create a relation between Class<A> and its Invokable<A, R>.
        final Invokable<A, R> invokable = invokables.get(a.getClass());
        try {
            return invokable.invoke(arg); // Type checked result (R).
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: Handle exception.
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This pattern is usually called the *Command* pattern.